# security implementation for js single-page application

Tags: security, single-page-application

How do u do security for a js single-page application ?
 By "security", i mean traditional webapp security, the kind of thing ,say, spring security does i.e. protecting resources based on url pattern, authentication implemented through web filters etc, then the authorization part , tying url-patterns to roles etc. The ajax calls for data can still intercepted, but what do u do for the view elements, say, loading modules based on roles etc.